# When entityManagerFactory is not named "entityManagerFactory"

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jpa, servlet-filters

My webapp contains many entityManagerFactories (DBs). Each has its own unique name, such as *entityManagerFactoryApp*, *entityManagerFactoryBusiness*, *entityManagerFactoryForum*, etc.

In the webapp I have to add `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` to achieve "Open Session in View" pattern.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

When running Spring throws the following error:

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is
> defined

But none of my entityManagerFactories is named *entityManagerFactory*.

I looked at the code of `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` and found `setEntityManagerFactoryBeanName()` method. How can I set it's value in web.xml?

Moreover, since I have multiple EMFs, should I define multiple `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`s in web.xml?

Environments : Spring 3.0.2 , Hibernate 3.5.1.Final , Resin 4.0.7 , JPA2 (hibernate-jpa-2.0-api)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` is a subclass of `GenericFilterBean`, which automatically translates filter init parameters into bean properties. So to set the `entityManagerFactoryBeanName` property on the filter, just use an init-param:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>      
      <param-value>entityManagerFactoryApp</param-value>       
   </init-param>
</filter>
```

You'll need one of these per `EntitymanagerFactory`, with the `entityManagerFactoryBeanName` set accordingly.